# Redirect echo output in shell script to logfile

Tags: shell, stdout

I have a shell script with lots of `echo` in it. I would like to redirect the output to a logfile.
I know there is the command call `cmd > logfile.txt`, or to do it in the file `echo 'xy' > logfile.txt`, but is it possible to simply set the filename in the script which then automatically writes all echo's to this file?

Comment: do you want to redirect *only* `echo`s? are there other commands producing output?

Comment: No other output besides echo's

Comment: I think it is the first question that I upvote the question plus 3 of the answers. All good. Great job, community!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add this line on top of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# redirect stdout/stderr to a file
exec >logfile.txt 2>&1
```

OR else to redirect only stdout use:

```
exec > logfile.txt
```

Comment: I want to write log in file and also want it to appear on console. Can you please guide what should I use for it.

Comment: I tried with this `exec > myLog.log 2>&1 | tee myLog.log` Its showing on console but not writing on file . I tried with `command | tee file.log` but this is also showing only on console.

Comment: Its writing only system date in file

Comment: Well that was all the output of command we used. ok better not to extend chat session on an unrelated question.

Comment: Will this one overwrites the log file every time the script is executed?

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: The Bashism `&>` is quite gratuitous here; the portable notation `>logfile.txt 2>&1` is more explicit but IMHO more readable as well as more portable (and easy then to change to `>>` whereas `&>>` was only introduced relatively recently, and isn't available on platforms which still only offer Bash 3, such as macOS).

Comment: Beware that neither tee nor redirect survives log file rotation.

Comment: Change `>` to `>>` for ability to rotate/truncate log files.

Answer (score 26):

I tried to manage using the below command. This will write the output in log file as well as print on console.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Log Location on Server.
LOG_LOCATION=/home/user/scripts/logs
exec > >(tee -i $LOG_LOCATION/MylogFile.log)
exec 2>&1

echo "Log Location should be: [ $LOG_LOCATION ]"
```

**Please note:** This is bash code so if you run it using sh it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: So how do I append rather than overwrite? Or can that not be done because we are writing to screen also? (I've tried modifying the line to "exec >> >(tee.." but it still overwrites)

Comment: @MarkSmith please use with `-a` option: `exec > >(tee -a $log)`

Comment: Of course! I kind of knew about the -a option with tee, but completely forgot. Thank you 

Comment: Above works perfectly; but curious could anymore explain how/why this work?

Comment: @Kelly The notation `>(cmd)` essentially creates a parallel process which runs `cmd` for the duration of the command which contains this process substitution, with its output redirected to standard input of `cmd`. The command `exec` is a special case here; its sole purpose is to create a process substitution until the end of the script, or the next `exec` which redirects the same file descriptor(s) to a different destination.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily redirect different parts of your shell script to a file (or several files) using sub-shells:

```
{
  command1
  command2
  command3
  command4
} > file1
{
  command5
  command6
  command7
  command8
} > file2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
LOG_LOCATION="/path/to/logs"    
exec >> $LOG_LOCATION/mylogfile.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/sh
# http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html
echo "Hello World"
exec > script.log 2>&1
echo "Start logging out from here to a file"
bad command
echo "End logging out from here to a file"
exec > /dev/tty 2>&1 #redirects out to controlling terminal
echo "Logged in the terminal"
```

Output:

```
> ./above_script.sh                                                                
Hello World
Not logged in the file
> cat script.log
Start logging out from here to a file
./logging_sample.sh: line 6: bad: command not found
End logging out from here to a file
```

Read more here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: The ABS is a rather dubious reference; it would probably be better to link to the official Bash reference manual, or to POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

To get output on console and log output in a file:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  #Command 1
  #Command 2
  #Command 3
  ...
) 2>&1 | tee /path/to/save/console_output.log
```